# http get returns error undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do a http get to a backend function to retrive data however when i run the javascript http triggers error instead and error is undefined. I don't understand what is going wrong as i don't get any kind of error.

**html**

```
<body ng-app="postApp" ng-controller="postController">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="tab">
            <div>
                <p ng-show="errors">{{errors}}</p>
                <p ng-show="message">Status: {{message}}</p>
                <form ng-submit="startJobs()">
                    <label ng-repeat="job in jobs">
                        <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                name="selectedJobs[]"
                                value="{{job.name}}"
                                ng-model="job.selected"
                        > {{job.name}}
                    </label>
                    <p/>
                    <input type="submit" id="startJobs" value="Start jobs" />
                </form>
            </div>

            <p ng-show="message">Status: {{status}}</p>
            <div>
                <form ng-submit="getJobStatus()">
                    <input type="submit" id="jobStatus" value="Progress" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
    var postApp = angular.module('postApp', []);
    postApp.controller('postController', function($scope, $http, filterFilter) {

        $scope.jobs = [
            { name: 'Response status', value: 'responseStatus', selected: true },
            { name: 'test', value: 'test', selected: false }
        ];

        $scope.selection = [];

        $scope.selectedJobs = function selectedJobs() {
            return filterFilter($scope.jobs, { selected: true });
        };

        $scope.$watch('jobs|filter:{selected:true}', function (nv) {
            $scope.selection = nv.map(function (jobs) {
                return jobs.name;
            });
        }, true);

        $scope.checkedJobs = [];

        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.startJobs = function() {
            angular.forEach($scope.jobs, function(value, key) {
                if(value.selected == true) {
                    $scope.checkedJobs.push(value.value);
                }
            });
            $http({
                method  : 'GET',
                url     : 'api/start_analyze/' + $scope.checkedJobs + '/',
                data    : $scope.user,
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data) {
                $scope.message = data;
            }).error(function(error){
                $scope.error = error; //here i get undefined on error.
            });
        };
        $scope.getJobStatus = function() {
            $http({
                method  : 'GET',
                url     : 'api/get_analyze_status/',
                data    : $scope.user,
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data) {
                $scope.status = data;
            }).error(function(error){
                $scope.error = error; //here i get undefined on error.
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: **Error from console**

> Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON
>   data
>   fromJson@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1271:9
>   defaultHttpResponseTransform@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9460:1
>   transformData/<@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9551:12
>   forEach@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:340:11
>   transformData@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9550:3
>   transformResponse@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10319:21
>   processQueue@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14792:28
>   scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14808:27
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16052:16
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15870:15
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16160:13
>   done@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10589:36
>   completeRequest@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10787:7
>   requestLoaded@http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10728:1
>
> http://localhost:8081/bower_components/angular/angular.js Line 12520

The response from the server side is.

> status = 200 response = "Started working" headersString =
>   "Content-Type: applicatio...tty(8.1.16.v20140903)\r\n" statusText =
>   "OK"

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict with the name? Try with the default naming parameters `function(data, status, headers, config)`.

Comment: can you provide sample output? seems in your response wrong json